# perl, mason, working and passing variables

Tags: perl, mason

I'm trying to pass a 'mason' variable into a Perl autohandler script that runs before the HTML.
Is this possible.

```
<!--- MASON -->
<html>
<body>
    <%init>
        my $sub_headline = 'this is text';
    </%init>
    ###HEADER###
</body>
</html>

<!--- AUTOHANDLER --->
my $m_header = '<div class="m-portlet__head">
<div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
  <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
    <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text">###TITLE###</h3>
  </div>
  <p>$sub_headline</p>
</div><!-- /.caption -->
</div><!-- /.head -->';
$html   =~ s/###HEADER###/${m_header}/i;
```

Comment: With js and liquid

Comment: I am not familiar with Mason at all, but I doubt regex is the answer here. Wait for someone who knows Mason to come by. I suggest you do some research though. Right now your question looks like a _do my work for me for free_ request.

Comment: Thanks for taking. I have been spinning my gears all night. I first went with regex, with no positive results.

Comment: Then please [edit] the question and show us what you've tried. Also see [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Ended up making a component for the header and adding a condition for the passed in arg. Then pirnt the correct HTML.